# Problems fetching desktop-full

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am getting several errors in downloading tf2 and geometry-experimental packages with wstool (ubuntu:precise).

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/55948/problems-fetching-desktop-full/) by [kurt.christofferson](https://answers.ros.org/users/4082/kurt.christofferson/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2013-02-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The rosinstall generator appears to be including things it shouldn't. See [this question](http://answers.ros.org/question/55363/errors-installing-rosdep/).

---

Originally posted by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) with karma: 9115 on 2013-02-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0